# User's saved items - category is None?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I would like to get the category for my saved items, but it looks like it's not working. An example:

[image]

I expect to get the title and "youtube" for the category.

```
import praw
from praw.models import Submission

reddit = praw.Reddit(...)

saved = reddit.user.me().saved(limit=10)

for item in saved:
    if isinstance(item, Submission):
        print(item.title)
        print(item.category)
    else:
        print("This is a comment, I don't care...for now.")
```

This gives me this result (copying here only the relevant part of course):

```
Spawn Revamp Design Doc Thoughts and Suggestions
None # <---- This should be "youtube"
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Using the .json "trick" (https://www.reddit.com/user/Arklur/saved.json), it also shows "null", if this helps.

[image]